# Can't Delete All Rows Which Are Not In Top 20 Using NOT EXISTS on MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have top scores of a game in a table named Scores. What I want to do is "Delete all scores which are not in both all time top 20 and 365 days top 20" in order to reduce database size. However, my query seems to be not working and/or have a syntax error.

I'm using MS Access .mdb file and asp.net c# windows forms to execute this query.

```
DELETE FROM
  Scores
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      TOP 20 *
    FROM
      Scores
    ORDER BY
      Points Desc
  )
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      TOP 20 *
    FROM
      Scores
    WHERE
      DateDiff("d", Date, NOW()) <= 365
    ORDER BY
      Points Desc
  )
```

My query seems to be not deleting any low scores.

Comment: Your subqueries aren't correlated. As long as there are records in `Scores` the query won't delete anything form `Scores`. But without knowing the schema it's impossible to give you a hint on how to correlate them. I also don't quite understand the meaning of the word "intercept" in that context.

Comment: Does any of your sub-queries return any result set?

Comment: Your AND should read OR. Also, replace Now() by Date()

Comment: @Rene If I say OR it may delete all time scores. As far as I know, there is no difference between Date() and Now()

Comment: @stickybit I have changed ASC with DESC

Comment: @Gouda I want to delete with SQL Query only, not with reader.

Comment: @Gouda I do cmd.executenonquery();

Comment: @Bora is there any unique id in the table?

Comment: @Bora you say: "Delete all scores which are not in **both** all time top 20 and 365 days top 20". The answer you accepted "deletes all scores that are not in **either** all time top 20 or 365 days top 20"

Comment: @Bora, I guess I misread. Anyway, if both conditions should apply then the overall top 20 condition is redundant. You only want the second condition, `DateDiff("d", Date, Date()) <= 365`

Comment: @Gouda solved my issue. Thanks for everyone for the contribution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a unique identifier on your table, let's assume it is named `ScoreId`. So your `delete` query should look like this:

```
DELETE FROM
  Scores
WHERE ScoreId
  NOT In (SELECT TOP 20 ScoreId FROM Scores 
          ORDER BY Points Desc)
  AND 
  NOT In (SELECT TOP 20 ScoreId FROM Scores 
          WHERE DateDiff("d", Date, NOW()) <= 365
          ORDER BY Points Desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a unique primary key like an id in your table, you can do this:

```
DELETE FROM SCORES
WHERE
ID NOT IN (
   SELECT TOP 20 ID 
   FROM Scores
   ORDER BY Points DESC)
OR 
ID NOT IN (
    SELECT TOP 20 ID
    FROM  Scores
    WHERE
        DateDiff("d", Date, NOW()) <= 365
    ORDER BY Points Desc)
```

Notice that I use `OR` instead of `AND`, because:
`(NOT IN A) OR (NOT IN B)` is equivalent to `NOT ((IN A) AND (IN B))`